# Bigbluebutton cant record notes at pdf presentation

Tags: bigbluebutton

I installed a bigbluebutton server in version 2.7 and was able to both broadcast and record it. However, during the recording, it was not possible to see the notes made in the presentation pdf. Is it necessary to configure any configuration for this to be possible?

Comment: @KJ this feature was working allright at version 2.4, so i think it might have some configuration to keep it up or something, but I cant find it in the documentation or the information that this no longer works